# What is the meaning of 都 in a structure of 连 什么 都 = 连 ... 都 = even ... sth？

Tags: grammar, meaning

[I've quoted the following sentences from here.](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22even%22_with_%22lian%22_and_%22dou%22)

> 这个 问题 太 简单 了 ，连 三岁 小孩 都 知道 。
>
> This question is so easy that even a three-year-old kid knows the answer.

For me, I think that removing 都 from this sentence still make sense.

What exactly this 都 is meaning here?

I used the dictionary and got the meanings as *all, both, entirely* .

So I think that adopting *entirely* is the best but I can't have a confidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**连** ~ **都**] is a set structure. It means  [**even** ~ (too)]

If you omit 都 and write "连 三岁 小孩 知道" The sentence would make no sense. It is like omitting "en" in "even" and writing "ev three years old children know"

- 连(even) 都(too)
- **连** XX **都** = **even** XX **too** --> **even** XX

*"too" can be omitted in English but "都" cannot be omitted in Chinese*

Answer (score 0):

**连** has the meanings of "even(甚至于)" and "include(包括)".

**都**, here, is an auxiliary word that means "all(统统,全)", which is required to connect the phrase "三岁小孩" and "知道" and put an emphasis tone on the complete phrase.

- 这个问题太简单了，**连(even)**三岁小孩**都(all)**知道。Note that the sentence remains valid after dropping the word "连":
- 这个问题太简单了，三岁小孩 **都/统统/全** 知道。